# Python - How to use regex search terms in text file

Tags: python, regex, function

I'm very new to coding, so any help would be appreciated.

So I have a regex function here to find certain terms in .txt files.

## function to return regex

```
def find_regex(start_regex, stop_regex, page_words_raw):
    # need to initialize because of bad return function
    start_char = None
    end_char_0 = None
    # searches the raw text for the start regex phrase
    for match in re.finditer(start_regex, page_words_raw):
        # just care about where the first character of the matched text starts ([0])
        start_char = match.span()[0]

    for match in re.finditer(stop_regex, page_words_raw[start_char:]):
        # but we need to know the start and end of the stop character so we can subtract it from the return
        # since we want to look for stop word after our start word we need to add the indexes lost
        # at the page_words_raw[start_char:] bit
        end_char_0 = match.span()[0] + start_char
        end_char_1 = match.span()[1] + start_char

    # if found return string minus the stop regex stuff
    if type(start_char) == int and type(end_char_0) == int:
        return page_words_raw[start_char : (end_char_1 - (end_char_1 - end_char_0))]
    else:
        print("Regex Not Found")
        return "Regext Not Found"
```

All .txt files will have different numbers (i.e. 4410, 4408, 4405, etc) and the next string will always be a letter followed by a sequence of 7 numbers (i.e. C90253453, D0004323, N1235423)

The function to find the four numbered sequence is:

```
    #this function finds 44xx, it's meant to stop at Mxxxxxxx 
    found_stuff = find_regex('44\d{2}', ('\s\d{7}'), page_words_raw)
```

When I run it, it returns the 4407 but does not stop at the C0243543. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: What is the exact output you expect here?

Answer (score 1):

If you can tolerate reading the entire file into Python, then your requirement is easy using `re.findall`:

```
text = """4410 C90253453 4408 D0004323 4405 N1235423"""
nums = re.findall(r'\b(\d{4})\s+[A-Z]\d+\b', text)
print(nums)
```

This prints:

```
['4410', '4408', '4405']
```